# Four clues, each with four clues - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

Here's an easy brain teaser.  Four clues, each with four clues.  The order isn't important.

Give me the answer to each set of clues and the word that connects them.  :)

> Where things go when things go wrong,
>
> and jugs accompany a song,
>
> Where white bears are furthest from,
>
> and emperors share a kingdom,
>
> -
>
> Not puzzling on hypotenuse,
>
> Instead something that sees my use,
>
> An ancient sport of men and birds,
>
> With better prizes for fewer words,
>
> -
>
> Artistic verse without a song,
>
> Before or aft I can belong,
>
> Rain and ice and fire before,
>
> Square, ball and belly are three more,
>
> -
>
> A shallow box oft home of men,
>
> Prone to sinking now and then,
>
> Not a key but found in locks,
>
> A shoving charge as well as box.

**What am I?**

HINT:

> a fifth clue to help with the final answer - Vault

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**First part**:

> **South**

*Where things go when things go wrong,*

> When a plan 'goes south', it's all gone horribly wrong

*and jugs accompany a song,*

> 'Jug bands' seem to have originated in the southern US

*Where white bears are furthest from,*

> Polar bears live at the north pole

*and emperors share a kingdom,*

> Emperor penguins live on Antarctica*

---

**Second part** (partial, with thanks to Hugh Meyers)*

> **Fishing***

*Not puzzling on hypotenuse,*

> We're not *angling*, we're fishing

*Instead something that sees my use,

> Something that uses the final answer

*An ancient sport of men and birds,*

> People (and birds) have been fishing/angling forever

*With better prizes for fewer words,*

> Fish ( stylised as ><>) is a language regularly used in the programming puzzles and code golf stack exchange (thanks, Neon612)

---

**Third Part** (partial)

> **Dance**

*Artistic verse without a song,*

> Music that is danced to tends not to have lyrics

*Before or aft I can belong,*
*Rain and ice and fire before,*

> Rain dance, the 'song of ice and fire' series' latest book is 'A dance with dragons'

*Square, ball and belly are three more*

> Square dancing, ball(room) dancing and belly dancing are all things*

---

**Fourth part***

> **Barge***

*A shallow box oft home of men,*
*Prone to sinking now and then,*
*Not a key but found in locks,*

> As a boat, people live in it, it can sink, and it passes through locks to go along a canal (and up or down)*

*A shoving charge as well as box.*

> You can barge into people*

**Final answer** (got before looking at the hint, honest!)

> **Pole** - South Pole, Fishing Pole, Pole Dancing, Bargepole

Comment: Hat must be keeping your brain warm.  You got the first part. +1  Just google a Jug Band.

Comment: That's clue 4 solved.  That hat is on fire!  Keep it up. :)

Comment: Well done!  You got part 3 but part 2 needs work.  Maybe you can guess the answer from three clues and work backwards?

Comment: Perhaps #2 has something to do with angling.

Comment: @HughMeyers Well done! :) +1

Comment: A 'word' can be 4 bits.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος These days a word is usually 32 bits but that's not something that will help to solve this one...  the final answer is just a word that can belong with the 4 answers.

Comment: Hint: You'll want to use the broader term for the answer to the second set of clues.  And while I'm at it, Fire and Ice are both just types of the third answer (although your connection is nerdier and therefore automatically better).

Comment: @BrentHackers so.. angle?

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat ...Fishing

Comment: Added a hint to help with the final word.

Comment: "better prizes for fewer words" could have something to do with code golf and the programming language Fish

Comment: @Neon612 They actually had that as their answer earlier :)  +1 Wrong direction in this case though.

Comment: I was just coming up with some awesome jokes about your hat being too tight and now I don't get to use them... :(  You got it @LogicianWithAHat Hint or no, well done! :)

Comment: @BrentHackers Thanks, it was a nice puzzle! Out of interest, what was the 'before or aft' bit in the third clue?

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat Just that I [the final answer] can appear before or after the third answer.  (and because I could make it rhyme)

Comment: @BrentHackers Whoops, I was comfused with bits and bytes!!! So it's 4 *bytes*...

Answer (score 1):

PARTIAL ANSWER

The first line:

This is

> Nowhere.

Where things go when things go wrong,

> "We're in the middle of nowhere!"

and jugs accompany a song,

> ...Nowhere

Where white bears are furthest from,

> You can't be close to nowhere :)

and emperors share a kingdom,

> Nowhere.

Comment: Gandalf... I'd expect better from you!  But then you did need a hobbit to solve the old "Speak friend to enter here." door puzzle so I shouldn't be too surprised.  What I'm trying to say is - There is a better fit!  (something that will connect with the answer to the other puzzles)  +1 by the way :)

Comment: @BrentHackers I'm several thousand years old. Give me a break. :P

Comment: "With age comes... What was I saying?"